# Smart Search (finder): Articles only search and suggestions format

Tags: php, search, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to search only articles with Joomla Smart Search. How can I do it? And I want suggestions into some specific format. Please guide me.

I did some research but didn't get proper answer

Comment: What format of suggestions are you looking for ?

Comment: not only word suggestion but whole article as suggestion....

Comment: For articles as suggestions, you didn't find answer with basic Smart search or with help of an extension ?

Comment: I don't totally understand what you mean, but do you mean you would like the article titles to show up?

Comment: I mean title of an article along with some other basic details..should come as suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Go to your plugin manager in Joomla's backend and disable all the "Smart Search" plugins except for "Smart Search - Content".

Comment: It's a partial answer, it would be better with the answer about customizing suggestions.

Comment: Like this it is searching in articles but in suggestions (as soon as I type) it is showing all the words. For example, If I type "s" it shws me every thing like "such", "school" etc but I want only article title along with other  text along if anywhere that word is there